# Retrieve data with its relations from a database

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am struggling to get data I need from my database.  So my structure is pretty straight forward, I have a questions table

```
quiz_question
    id (PK)
    question (text)
    type (text)

quiz_answer
    id (PK)
    question_id (FK)
    answer (text)
```

So my database may look a bit like so for a question and answer.

```
quiz_question

id  |   question               |  type
----------------------------------------
1   |   What is your gender    |  radio


quiz_answer 

id  |   question_id   |  answer
------------------------------------
1   |   1             |  Male
------------------------------------
2   |   1             |  Female
------------------------------------
3   |   1             |  Non-binary
```

So what I am trying to do is build up some JSON to return the questions with their associated answers, something like the following.

```
{
    questions [{
        id: 1,
        question: 'What is your gender',
        type: 'radio',
        answers: [
            {
                'Male'
            },
            {
                'Female'
            },
            {
                'Non-binary'
            }
        ]
      }...
    ]
}
```

I am trying to form an SQL query but getting a bit lost, currently I have

```
select quiz_question.question, quiz_question.helptext,
        quiz_question.imageurl, quiz_question.questiontype 
FROM quiz_question 
    INNER JOIN quiz_answer on quiz_question.id = quiz_answer.questionId;
```

However, that seems to return a strange dataset.  So how can I query my database to retrieve the questions with their answers?

Thanks

Comment: *"that seems to return a strange dataset"* - What's strange about it?  What's the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: You dont actually want most of the columns you are selecting... So dont select them. And you dont select the columns you actually want to see, so select them

Comment: Are you coding in javascript or PHP? Please show us the actual code that goes with the query you have shown us

Comment: Your problem is that you need to `quiz_answer.answer` to dataset, BUT also rearrange the dataset by grouping each Question together along with their corresponding answers. Some JS codes will do that for you, or you could use packages like `Knex` for Query Builder or `Bookshelf` as ORM built on top of `Knex` to handle relations auto, or like `Sequelize` that does both Query Builder and ORM.

Comment: I added an answer independently from Database, to show you algorithms on how you might rearrange data yourself to load your relations manually with no package.

Comment: Also `questionId` should be `question_id` to match your table field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use `Knex`, `Bookshelf`, `Sequelize` packages as I stated in the comments.

To do this manually, with an acceptable Time Complexity, let's take a basic query like this:

```
SELECT quiz_question.id, quiz_question.question, quiz_question.type, quiz_answer.answer
FROM quiz_question 
    INNER JOIN quiz_answer on quiz_question.id = quiz_answer.question_id;
```

Let's say it give you have this dataset, an array of multiple objects (ROWS):

```
const dataset = [
  {
    id: 1,
    question: 'Question 1',
    type: 'radio',
    answer: 'Answer 1 For Q1'
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    question: 'Question 1',
    type: 'radio',
    answer: 'Answer 2 For Q1'
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    question: 'Question 1',
    type: 'radio',
    answer: 'Answer 3 For Q1'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    question: 'Question 2',
    type: 'radio',
    answer: 'Answer 1 For Q2'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    question: 'Question 2',
    type: 'radio',
    answer: 'Answer 2 For Q2'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    question: 'Question 2',
    type: 'radio',
    answer: 'Answer 3 For Q2'
  }
];
```

Now you need to rearrange stuff. You could use multiple loops with `Array.map` and combine them, or one with `Array.forEach` or better `Array.reduce` :

```
let group = dataset.reduce((acc, data) => {
  if (!acc[data.id]) {
    acc[data.id] = {
      id: data.id,
      question: data.question,
      type: data.type,
      answers: []
    }
  };

  acc[data.id].answers.push({ answer: data.answer });
  return acc;
}, {});
```

This:

- Starts with empty object `{}`,
- Checks if object not yet contains a question id `{ id: ... }` to fill the object with the question data, AND to initialize and empty Array of Answers for that question `{ answers: [] }`.
- Pushes each answer that match the current question id into that answers array

And finally, the `group` is an Object, get rid of the `id`'s to have your original Array of Objects using `Object.values` that takes only the Value parts in (key => value) of and object:

```
let result = Object.values(group);
```

Answer (score 2):

As RiggsFolly said, it seems from the JSON you're trying to create, you would only want to do the following:

```
SELECT q.id, q.question, q.questiontype, a.answer AS answers
FROM quiz_question q
INNER JOIN quiz_answer a ON q.id = a.questionId;
```

But that is just a start. I think KeitelDOG is right in that you might want to consider rearranging the dataset, assuming the answer choices for questions will not change later. If some other questions have a different type of answer, like if the user will enter some information and that answer will be inserted, then it might be better to keep them separate and do JOINs like this when necessary.

To get the object from that JOIN, you would likely want to do something like the following after the query, assuming you're in JavaScript using a [promise().query](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2#using-promise-wrapper):

```
.then(([rows]) => {
    console.log(rows);
}
```

That will at least show you what's returned, then you can go from there depending on your needs.